# job.xml - Character reference "&#0" is an invalid XML character

Tags: hadoop, hive, hadoop-yarn

We are getting a strange job.xml error while running a mapreduce task. I am not able to get to the job.xml as well. The following is my environment.

Hadoop - 2.6.2
Hive   - 1.1.0

```
2017-03-10 02:13:11,788 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster: Created MRAppMaster for application appattempt_1488810291982_0019_000002
2017-03-10 02:13:11,953 FATAL [main] org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration: error parsing conf job.xml
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:///tmp/hadoop-hadoop/nm-local-dir/usercache/hadoop/appcache/application_1488810291982_0019/container_1488810291982_0019_02_000001/job.xml; lineNumber: 1027; columnNumber: 141; Character reference "&#0" is an invalid XML character.
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(DocumentBuilder.java:150)
at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.parse(Configuration.java:2432)
at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.loadResource(Configuration.java:2501)
at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.loadResources(Configuration.java:2454)
at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getProps(Configuration.java:2361)
at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.get(Configuration.java:1188)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.util.MRWebAppUtil.initialize(MRWebAppUtil.java:51)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster.main(MRAppMaster.java:1421)
2017-03-10 02:13:11,955 FATAL [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster: Error starting MRAppMaster
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:///tmp/hadoop-hadoop/nm-local-dir/usercache/hadoop/appcache/application_1488810291982_0019/container_1488810291982_0019_02_000001/job.xml; lineNumber: 1027; columnNumber: 141; Character reference "&#0" is an invalid XML character.
at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.loadResource(Configuration.java:2597)
at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.loadResources(Configuration.java:2454)
at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getProps(Configuration.java:2361)
at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.get(Configuration.java:1188)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.util.MRWebAppUtil.initialize(MRWebAppUtil.java:51)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster.main(MRAppMaster.java:1421)
```

Comment: some spacial character at tmp/hadoop-hadoop/nm-local-dir/usercache/hadoop/appcache/application_1488810291982_0019/container_1488810291982_0019_02_000001/job.xml; lineNumber: 1027; columnNumber: 141

Comment: @sandeeprawat - Thanks for your response. I am not able to get that job.xml. Is there a setting which can be configured to keep that directory and job.xml ? Looks like it gets removed immediately after the job fails.

Comment: <property>
                <name>yarn.nodemanager.delete.debug-delay-sec</name>
                <value>100000000</value>
 </property>
that property helped me to keep the job.xml. Investigating the XML now